# Deleting quotes from list items based on index

Tags: python, list

I have a 2-D numpy array in list format. Here’s snippet

```
[['0', '05:15', '07:12', '315', '432', '117', '901',  '0'], ['1', '05:25', '07:24', '325', '444', '119', '902',  '0'], ['2', '06:24', '07:37', '384', '457', '73', '903', '901'], ['3', '07:12', '07:49', '432', '469', '37', '901', '902'], ['4', '07:12', '08:13', '433', '493', '61', '903', '901']]
```

I used `sample1.to_numpy().tolist()` where sample1 is my DataFrame.

I want this list in this format.

```
[[0, '04:30', '04:53', 270, 293, 23],
[1, '04:46', '04:56', 286, 296, 10]]
```

Basically I need to remove quotes from selected index of elements for all rows in list
I tried `strip()` and `replace()` but just remained same.
Could someone please share way to achieve this.

Comment: You aren't deleting quotes; you are creating `int` values from `str` values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use list comprehension like so:

```
>>> [[int(s) if s.isdigit() else s for s in l] for l in sample1]
[[0, '05:15', '07:12', 315, 432, 117, 901, 0],
 [1, '05:25', '07:24', 325, 444, 119, 902, 0],
 [2, '06:24', '07:37', 384, 457, 73, 903, 901],
 [3, '07:12', '07:49', 432, 469, 37, 901, 902],
 [4, '07:12', '08:13', 433, 493, 61, 903, 901]]
```

If you expect to have `float` values and would like to cast to float instead:

```
>>> [[float(s) if s.isnumeric() else s for s in l] for l in sample1]
[[0.0, '05:15', '07:12', 315.0, 432.0, 117.0, 901.0, 0.0],
 [1.0, '05:25', '07:24', 325.0, 444.0, 119.0, 902.0, 0.0],
 [2.0, '06:24', '07:37', 384.0, 457.0, 73.0, 903.0, 901.0],
 [3.0, '07:12', '07:49', 432.0, 469.0, 37.0, 901.0, 902.0],
 [4.0, '07:12', '08:13', 433.0, 493.0, 61.0, 903.0, 901.0]]
```

#### Edit:

If you only want to cast the elements at certain indices (for example, 0th 4th and 5th):

```
>>> [[int(s) if i in [0, 4, 5] else s for i, s in enumerate(l)] for l in sample1]
[[0, '05:15', '07:12', '315', 432, 117, '901', '0'],
 [1, '05:25', '07:24', '325', 444, 119, '902', '0'],
 [2, '06:24', '07:37', '384', 457, 73, '903', '901'],
 [3, '07:12', '07:49', '432', 469, 37, '901', '902'],
 [4, '07:12', '08:13', '433', 493, 61, '903', '901']]
```

Comment: So it works for all int values, what if I don't want all int to be like that like last element if I need in single quotes then how to handle that ?